# how to setup qiwi payment gateway in rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment-gateway

Are there any documentations to integrate payment gateway with qiwi (for russian ruble) on ruby on rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this documentation:
https://ishop.qiwi.ru/docs/OnlineStoresProtocols_SOAP.pdf

and this gem: http://savonrb.com/

Comment: btw, I rolled out my solution https://github.com/romanbsd/qiwi , it's still an alpha quality, but you're welcome to hack it and send pull requests :)

Comment: are there any sandbox uri for qiwi payment gateway so that i can test my development scheme in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: No, but you can easily arrange one using soapUI application.